# Magento | Currency switcher not working when product is already in cart

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento store version 1.9.2.3 setup on subdomain. Currency switcher works fine when there is no product in cart. But when i add any product in cart and then apply currency switching i receive following errors

- on local i am getting a blank page
- on subdomain i am getting 500 server error

I have already done this in index.php

```
ini_set("memory_limit", '512M');
ini_set("max_execution_time", '120');
```

But issue remains same. Please provide any help if possible.

Comment: Have you checked your logs?

Comment: I have checked the logs, no log is generated. Without adding product to cart currency switcher is working but when product added to cart it is not working.

Comment: My magento version is 1.9.2.3. I have checked with the default theme version even. It is not working. Please help

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, first find out if you are using any extensions for cart and checkout pages other than the magento default one.

if so , search for the code in those extension files

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
```

replace this code with

```
$quoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId();
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
```

The reason is because of when you added the product to the cart and switch the currency

the below sql code is fired and it will check for the code items details causes an infinite loop of getting the quote items. This causes an empty page or internal server error

```
SELECT `sales_flat_quote`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote` WHERE (`sales_flat_quote`.`entity_id`='1055') AND (store_id IN ('1'))
```